# How can I ensure two floated items stay side-by-side even if there isn’t enough width for both of them?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div  >
  <div >
    <div style="float: left;">
      <input type="checkbox" value="False" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;" >         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It displays the XXX to the right of the checkbox. However, if I reduce the screen width, the XXX goes under the checkbox.

Is there any way that I can "lock" the XXX text inside the DIV so the XXXX always appears to the right and on the same line?

(Note that I want to keep using DIV as later on I do some jQuery things with the DIVs.)

Comment: +1 for nice and clear question with relevant formatted code block

Comment: @Bad: terrible original title though.

Answer (score 4):

If you want them to always be on the same line, you can reasonably combine the two divs into one, still floated, and use the `white-space` property to keep it on one line:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="float:left; white-space:nowrap;">
      <input type="checkbox" value="false" />         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Starx's answer explains very well why it's not really feasible to do this with two separate floated divs.

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/nkorth/qQSCV/

Comment: I prefer this technique, but definitely with `<label>` instead of a div.

Comment: Well yeah, but I was just working with his original code. It's always a good idea to use `<label>`s in forms.

Comment: Oh yes I know, OP explicitly stated he needed/wanted `<div>` - just wanted to point out that this technique works very well, if you hadn't posted it I would have.

Answer (score 3):

yep, you can do that by setting fixed width for the container, like so:

```
<div>
  <div style="width:400px">
    <div style="float: left;">
      <input type="checkbox" value="False" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;" >         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is what `float:left` is supposed to do. It will remain in the left side as much as possible. If the element before is also floated to the left side, it will try to float to left, together with it, if the space is available. That's why when you resize your screen and there is not enought space for the div to float to the together with previous element, it will float to the left, down the previous element.

Comment: This will force the "XXXXX" `div` to always be below the `div` with the checkbox. I think what he wants is to keep them horizontally aligned with each other, which is what @Bad Display Name's answer does.

Comment: i think the user wants the opposite effect (read the question). he wants the 2 divs to always stay inline.

Comment: @Bad Display Name, Oops, my mistake. I will update my answer, then again... why bother, you got it already :)